# Why my C# Code isn't Printing the Required Output

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, exponent

I attempting to create a program that uses multiple methods that would print out base numbers, exponents, and their resulting solutions. I am trying to get it to run and it's nearly completed, but I am encountering a couple issues. The code itself seems to run, but doesn't appear to print out on Visual Studio. I did run it on an online compiler and got this as an output:

[image]

It seems I am missing something in my code, but I am unclear as to what I may be missing. This is the code I have created for the project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Our initialized variables.
            int intMinBase = 1;
            int intMaxBase = 100;

            int intMinExpo = 1;
            int intMaxExpo = 10;

            //Our arrays for the project, all at a length of 5.
            long[] baseNumbers = new long[5];
            long[] exponents = new long[5];
            long[] results = new long[5];

            //Randomize the baseNumbers and exponents!
            Random randInt = new Random();
            for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                baseNumbers[i] = randInt.Next(intMinBase, intMaxBase);
                exponents[i] = randInt.Next(intMinExpo, intMaxExpo);
            }

            PrintArrays(baseNumbers, exponents, results);
        }

        //This is potentially experimental code for the Power Method.
        public static int Power(int baseNum, int exponent)
        {
            int answer;

            if (exponent == 1)
            {
                answer = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                answer = baseNum * Power(baseNum, exponent - 1);
            }

            return answer;
        }


        //The new method to be printed. Is this the correct manner to display this?
        public static void PrintArrays(long[] baseNum, long[] exponent, long[] result)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"Base\tExponent\tResult");

            for (int print = 0; print < result.GetUpperBound(0); print++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(baseNum[print]+"\t"+exponent[print]+"\t"+result[print]);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

My question is mainly am I missing something and why isn't it appearing to print in Visual Studio yet it's appearing on an online compiler? I suspect the answer to the first part of the question has to do with the methods I used, but I am unsure.

Comment: You're never calling your "experimental" `Power` function. That's why the results are all zero.

Comment: " I did run it on an online compiler and got this as an output:" Okay, and what is wrong with this output? How is it different from the output you expect?

Comment: @DStanley Ah, that makes sense. We just started getting into creating methods and I wasn't sure what was wrong with it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It's due to that the results are zero.

Answer (score 2):

First error: Nowhere is the method Power called and nowhere is the array results filled.

Solution example:

```
for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    baseNumbers[i] = randInt.Next(intMinBase, intMaxBase);
    exponents[i] = randInt.Next(intMinExpo, intMaxExpo);
    results[i] = Power(baseNumbers[i], exponents[i]);
}
```

Comment: That's definitely getting there though it seems that the program is saying that I can't convert 'long' into 'int'. I definitely makes sense that I forgot to call it though. I thought I was done up there, but it seems not to be the case. There is the convert function, but that doesn't appear to have worked as I hoped.